# PHP include not launching

Tags: php

Hi I have a simple database connection test php file (index.php) that is supposed to call another page (output.html.php) with the include statement but it does not seem to work. Please help. Below is the code for both files. Thank you.

`index.php`:

```
<?php
try
{
        $pdo =  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ijdb', 'ijdbuser', 'mypassword');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ALTER_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $PDO->exec('SET NAMES "utf8");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
        $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
        include = 'output.html.php';
        exit();
}

$output = 'Database connection established.';
include 'output.html.php';
?>
```

`output.html.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" >
        <title>DB Example</title>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>

                <p>
                <?php echo $output; ?>
                </p>

        </body
</html>
```

I just get blank page.

Comment: BTW, the two files are in the same directory.

Comment: Yeah, uhm.. That's not how `include()` works in php.

Comment: A blank age is usually a good indicator of something going wrong on the server, and no error reporting is enabled. Check the error log on your server.

Comment: add `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the beginning and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 2):

```
include 'output.html.php';
```

not

```
include = 'output.html.php';
```

Remove the `=`

Comment: There are 3 problems, there is an exception being raised and the first include isn't properly stated, with error reporting disabled you have a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

```
    index.php:

    <?php
    try
    {

            $pdo =  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ijdb', 'ijdbuser', 'mypassword');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ALTER_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");//$PDO->exec('SET NAMES "utf8");

            header("location:output.html.php?msg=Database%20connection%20established");
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
                            header("location:output.html.php?msg=Unable%20to%20connect%20to%20the%20database%20server");

    }

?>
```

what i understand if you include file it redirect to that page which is blank and hence no massage($output) is show.if you apply redirect method you move to required message show on failure and success.

output.html.php:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" >
        <title>DB Example</title>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>

                <p>
                <?php if(isset($_GET['msg'])){echo $_GET['msg'];} ?>
                </p>

        </body
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you misstiped the end of string in the question and already solved it. Anyway, here is a little error: index.php, first try{} block:

```
...
$PDO->exec('SET NAMES "utf8");
...
```

It should be:

```
$PDO->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

Hope it help you. As you can see in the answers and comments, enabling errors in PHP development enviroment is the best way to solve this "white screen of death" errors. Here is a reference about this last topic: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#89648

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding. I tried all the above changes but it still does not redirect to included file. I'll do some reading on the link provided.